# momentum of a massless particle

Tags: special-relativity, photons, momentum

I'm still struggling with the idea of a massless particle (photon) having momentum.

if p = mv then if m=0, p=0

Even in the approach of :

p = mv / Sqrt(1-v^2/c^2)  = p=ymv

if velocity is equal to the speed of light, p would still equal 0?

am I missing something here?

thanks